# firebase auth.sendSignInLinkToEmail method is not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

i installed firebase in react app and initialized like this

```
// Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAuth, GoogleAuthProvider } from "firebase/auth"
// TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries

// Your web app's Firebase configuration
const firebaseConfig = {....};

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

// export
export const auth = getAuth(app);
export const googleAuthProvider = new GoogleAuthProvider();
```

and imported this file into my react component like this

```
import {auth} from '../../firebase';
```

and i try to use it like this

```
await auth.sendSignInLinkToEmail(email, config);
```

and it give me this error

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Firebase v9+, you need to use the modular [`sendSignInLinkToEmail()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/auth.md#sendsigninlinktoemail):

```js
import { auth } from '../../firebase';
import { sendSignInLinkToEmail } from "firebase/auth"

await sendSignInLinkToEmail(auth, email, config);
```

You can catch these errors yourself by familiarizing yourself with the [namespaced SDK to modular SDK upgrade process](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade).